# What is a data binding?

Tags: data-binding, glossary

What is a data binding?

Answer (score 12):

Binding generally refers to a mapping of one thing to another - i.e. a datasource to a presentation object. It can typically refer to binding data from a database, or similar source (XML file, web service etc) to a presentation control or element - think list or table in HTML, combo box or data grid in desktop software.

You generally have to bind the presentation element to the datasource, not the other way around. This would involve some kind of mapping - i.e. which fields from the datasource do you want to appear in the output.

For more information in a couple of environments see:

- Data binding in .Net using Windows Forms

  - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databindingconcepts.aspx
  - http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html
- ASP.NET data binding

  - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860
  - http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040630.htm
  - [http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_databinding.asp](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)
- Java data binding

  - http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/03/binding.html
- Python data binding

  - http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/07/27/py-xml.html
- General XML data binding

  - http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDataBinding.htm