# What language is MonoDevelop IDE written in?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm doing research for a school paper and am a little confused by the wording on the MonoDevelop webpage.  It reads:

> MonoDevelop was originally a port of the SharpDevelop IDE to Gtk#, but
>   it has evolved a lot since the initial port....Since its written in
>   Gtk#, and we like Gtk# and we get good support from Gtk#, most likely
>   it will add functionality to improve the Gtk# experience. *(MonoDevelop.com/FAQ, 2012)*

The quote says that its written in GTK#, but when I cloned the MonoDevelop repo and examined its source code, all of the files were in **C#**.  Can someone please bridge the gap and explain why the website would say GTK# while the source files dictate otherwise?

One other question -- the StackOverflow description of GTK# reads as:

> Gtk# is a C# binding of the Gtk+ widget library.

Exactly what does this mean?  Is a "binding" the same thing as a "wrapper" class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *programming language* that (most of) MonoDevelop is written in **C#**.

**Gtk#** is a toolkit for creating graphical user interfaces that can be used in C# programs. That means, MonoDevelop's graphical user interface is built using Gtk#.

And, yes, Gtk# is a C# wrapper around the Gtk+ C++ GUI toolkit (not a single wrapper class, rather a collection of many C# classes, more or less each of which wraps one of the original Gtk+ classes).

Answer (score 3):

C# is the programming language used to write MonoDevelop; Gtk# is the bridge between the C# language and the GTK+ toolkit that is used to provide its user interface (hence the sort of combined name). So yes, you can sort of call Gtk# a C# "wrapper" for the GTK+ library. The word "binding" here refers to a [language binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865/what-is-a-language-binding).

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop is written in C#.

use this link : http://www.mono-project.com/Start